# Linq to SQL in ASP.NET - keep DB connections open

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, sqlconnection

I know that it's not a good practice to keep a DataContext alive and re-use it, so I wrapped it in a Using statement.

Also, as far as I know, DataContext opens a connection when it's being initialized, and closes the connection when it's disposed.

What I'm looking to accomplish here, is keeping a separate connection open for each currently logged in user (and close the connection manually when the user logs out).

Multithreading is not an issue, because I'm using locks.

I keep SQLConnections and pass them to the DataContext constructor. This sort of works. But the problem is that DataContext automatically closes the connection when it's disposed.

Is it somehow possible to force the DataContext to not close the connection it uses?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?   And just because you are using locks does not mean you can use the same connection on more than one thread.

Answer (score 2):

In general, your pain point will occur if you try and execute some sort of loop through records, and you create a `DataContext` (and, by extension, a SQL Connection) each time.  As long as you don't do that, you shouldn't have any major performance problems.

The notion of holding a SQL Connection open so that you can pass it to a DataContext is premature optimization, in my opinion.  SQL Connections are not *that* expensive, and neither are `DataContext` objects.

In general, the lifetime of your `DataContext` object should be the same as the lifetime of your associated Repository object.

**Example**

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    private MyDatabaseDataContext dataContext;

    public CustomerRepository()
    {
        dataContext = new MyDatabaseDataContext();
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        return dataContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
    }

    public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersByRep(int repID)
    {
        return dataContext.Customers.Where(x => x.repID == repID);
    }
}
```

**See Also** 
[ASP.NET MVC Tip #34 – Dispose of Your DataContext (or Don’t)](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx)

Comment: On top of that, SQL Connections are pooled, so they're not actually opened and closed physically.